# Failed connect to 'ems': error=11, message=Server not connected

Tags: tibco-ems

I am having a bit of issue trying to secure the EMS server. I am getting the error below after I type the following command;

```
./tibemsadmin -server tcp://ems-oss-1y.adb.XXX.dolmen.bouyguestelecom.fr:7333 -user admin -password "password" -script /opt/instance/tibco/script_shutdown.ems
```

> Error : Failed connect to
>   'tcp://ems-oss-1y.adb.XXX.dolmen.bouyguestelecom.fr:7333': error=11,
>   message=Server not connected

Anyone with the idea on how to resolve this...

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because it's inappropriate to edit your post and add SOLVED and the solution. If you found an answer and want to share, then write an answer in the space provided below as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you'd prefer not to do so, then you can either wait and hope that someone does so for you, or delete the question using the link below the tags. You can find more info in the [help]. Thanks.

Comment: I already had written an answer. Thanks for deleting my work.
I spent time here for nothing,

Comment: Don't blame me because you didn't do things right. :-) You did not write an answer. You edited a solution into your question, which is not how things work here (as I spent my time explaining in my first comment). An answer is written in the space below that has the heading **Your Answer** above it.

Comment: Who is the experienced moderator?
Why did not you leave a note for me to change the post?
When did you start participating in this forum, you were treated like that too?

Comment: When you created your account, you were asked to take the [tour] and read the [help] pages. If you had done so, you most likely would have seen the post about self-answers. Again, you can't blame me because you made a mistake. There are thousands of new users here, and no one has time to babysit all of them. New users have some responsibility to learn how the site works before posting here.

Comment: But to help: Click the `edited XX mins ago` above my name (next to yours) in the question, which takes you to the history of edits on this post. You can copy your answer from the question there, and use it to paste into a new answer below.